# Modulo with two divisors?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I've been trying to implement AKS algorithm, an algorithm that helps to identify if an integer is prime or not. One of the steps mentions the following:

> If for all $a$ from 1 to $\lfloor\sqrt{r}\log{n}\rfloor$ it is true, that $(x+a)^n\equiv x^n+a\quad(\mod f(x),n)$, then return "Prime".

I would like to know three things:

1) If $r$ and $n$ are known and are integers, why do we need to find the minimum of their product? Or do these brackets mean something else?

2)I've seen many time modulo being written with something else after the first divisor. Usually it's something simple like $\mod{4}$, but here there is also $n$ after the totient function. What does it mean?

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$

Comment: For the second question, have a look at the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test, which explains also that the congruence is between polynomials, so $x$ is the unknown

Comment: @zar I see. So it's basically we round the integer. That explain it, thanks! Anything you might know about other things?